# SAPUI5 formatting based on partial model

Tags: sapui5

In following an SAPUI5 course/tutorial, I learned how to format a number as currency the following way: (this is App.view.xml)

```
                                items="{/ProductSet}">
                                <items>
                                    <ObjectListItem
                                        title="{Name}"
                                        number="{
                                            parts: [
                                                {path: 'Price'},
                                                {path: 'CurrencyCode'}
                                            ],
                                            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                                            formatOptions: {
                                                currencyCode: false
                                            }
                                        }"
                                        ...
```

This works fine.  Both Price and CurrencyCode are in my model.

How would one format a number in my model that is known to be a specific currency (like USD or EUR)?  I tried changing

```
{path: 'CurrencyCode'}
```

to just

```
'USD'
```

But that did not show a dollar sign.  Is this possible without writing a custom formatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a viewmodel (that is a separate named JSONModel which contains some constants an options for use in a view, created in the controllers `onInit()`) and put the currency in there:

```
<ObjectListItem
                                    title="{Name}"
                                    number="{
                                        parts: [
                                            {path: 'Price'},
                                            {path: 'view>/CurrencyCode'}
                                        ],
                                        type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                                        formatOptions: {
                                            currencyCode: false
                                        }
                                    }"
```

and in the controller:

```
onInit:function() {
  this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({ CurrencyCode: "USD"}), "view");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  It sounds like there is no way to hard-code a currency code in this particular example (in the app view), but having a small "static" model in this case is a pretty simple way to simulate it.